# FOIA website - 90% of requests are "Under Agency Review"? What am I missing?

Tags: united-states, foia

https://foiaonline.gov/foiaonline/action/public/search/advancedSearch

The vast majority of entries on "Under Agency Review" with no details, requester names or requester organizations. Even requests submitted back in 2020. What am I missing? **Does the FOIA just never get round to 90% of requests or is there something else?**

---

ETA: My question is different than the one answered here: [FOIA request takes too long](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/65173/foia-request-takes-too-long)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question - can someone please actually read my question? You'll notice it's different.

Comment: What should someone enter in the drop down fields to see the specific results you are asking about?

Comment: Honestly if you search for anything. Or if you hit advanced search and don't put anything except for "Received Date" and search for things in the last 18 months or any period.

Comment: Voted to reopen because it doesn't look like a duplicate question at all. I'm not sure if it's possible for us to answer it without insider knowledge of the workings of the government,  but it doesn't seem like a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 2):

Government compliance with FOIA is notoriously bad.  I found the following article in the Duke Law Journal illuminating: [FOIA, INC.](https://scholarship.law.duke.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3846&context=dlj).  There are some eye-opening statistics in there, like p.1375:

> At the end of FY 2014, the oldest pending requests across the federal
> government dated back to 1993.

More details on the response times from several large federal agencies begins on p.1423.  (The article goes into detail to show how, in those agencies, commercial requesters have overwhelmed even well-funded FOIA offices.)

It seems that the largest issue in compliance is a lack of resources.  Apparently, "We don't have funding to comply with the law" is an acceptable response for the executive branch.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should try this response with the IRS... (don't do that :))

Comment: @Someone IRS **has** the resources to force you to comply. filing a FOIA to force compliance with FOIA only reduces resources.